# How does assignment to dynamic object work in C#?

Tags: c#

In ASP.NET MVC the property `ViewBag` is of type dynamic.

[Throught the code](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-view), various "properties" of `ViewBag` are assigned to:

```
ViewBag.Message = "Hello world";
ViewBag.Title = "Page title";
```

How does this work? From reading the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) I get that `ViewBag` itself can by anything, but why (or how) does assigning something to a "member" of dynamic type work?

Here is how `ViewBag` is defined in `public abstract class ControllerBase : IController` class:

```
 [Dynamic]
 public dynamic ViewBag { get; }
 //
 // Summary:
 //     Gets or sets the dictionary for view data.
 //
 // Returns:
 //     The dictionary for the view data.
 public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }
```

Just curious.

*Relevant question:* [Where can I find the official documentation for DynamicViewDataDictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735423/where-can-i-find-the-official-documentation-for-dynamicviewdatadictionary)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ViewBag`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/087a8e54f9de#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fControllerBase.cs) is an [`ExpandoObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) or something similar. This is basically just a glorified Dictionary with the "properties" being the keys.

**UPDATE**:
Actually, it is a [`DynamicViewDataDictionary`](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/087a8e54f9de#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fDynamicViewDataDictionary.cs), a class internal to the ASP.NET MVC source code. This class inherits from [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) and simply is a wrapper around a `ViewDataDictionary`, in case of the `ViewBag` around the `ViewData` property of `ControllerBase`.
As you can see in `TryGetMember` and `TrySetMember` the calls are delegated to the `ViewData` without any logic.

Comment: How do you know this? When I look at the definition of `ViewBag` property, I don't see any references to `ExpandoObject`? I'll update my question with relevant definition.

Comment: @drozzy Well if you read the document linked by Daniel then you'll see you have to do `dynamic sampleObject = new ExpandoObject();` to instantiate an `ExpandoObject`, and as you said `ViewBag` is declared as: `public dynamic ViewBag { get; }` ...

Comment: @drozzy: To be honest, I don't know that it is an `ExpandoObject` exactly. I guess it also could be something else implementing `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`.

Comment: @Paul Sorry but I still don't get it. ExpandoObject is not used anywhere that I can see in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @drozzy: When you have a look [at the source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/087a8e54f9de#src%2fSystem.Web.Mvc%2fControllerBase.cs), you see that it is - in fact - not an `ExpandoObject` but an `DynamicViewDataDictionary`. This class inherits [`DynamicObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.aspx) which in turn implements the interface I mentioned in my last comment: `IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`. This class is simply a wrapper around a dictionary, in that case around `ControllerBase.ViewData`.

Answer (score 0):

"Visual C# 2010 introduces a new type, dynamic. The type is a static type, but an object of type dynamic bypasses static type checking. In most cases, it functions like it has type object. At compile time, an element that is typed as dynamic is assumed to support any operation. Therefore, you do not have to be concerned about whether the object gets its value from a COM API, from a dynamic language such as IronPython, from the HTML Document Object Model (DOM), from reflection, or from somewhere else in the program. However, if the code is not valid, errors are caught at run time."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx